# Basic authentication for subsite only

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication

I have a single site, which I want to protect. It's `/phpinfo` on the website.

There are several redirects. My apache file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
... A list of RewriteRules
RewriteRule ^(phpinfo)$ index.php?controller=$1
```

**index.php** takes **controller** as an argument and includes the specific site that is viewed.

I use basic authentication like this on several places already, which works fine:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/....../.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Protected content"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET>
    require valid-user
</Limit>
```

**But, the question is** how can I limit this basic authentication to `/phpinfo` on the server, so only this site is protected? Ideally the `AuthUserFile` points to a relative directory so I can deploy this on the live server without needing to change this path.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using PHP and not htaccess. It's simple yet effective.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != Config::AdminUser || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != Config::AdminPassword)
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected content"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die('Protected content');
}
```